# Runtime Error Message: Line 17: index -3 out of bounds for type 'int [256]'

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I need help to understand an issue with my C code. I am trying to find longest substring within a given string without character repetition. When run on the leetcode platform, the code below gives me an error for the String `"amqpcsrumjjufpu"`:

> Runtime Error Message: Line 17: index -3 out of bounds for type 'int [256]'

However, the same code works fine when I run it from my computer or any online editor. Please help me to understand this behaviour difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char* s) {
    char *h = s;
    int A[256] = {0};
    int length = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int max = 0;

    int len = strlen(s);

    for(int i = 0; i < len;i ++){
        int A[256] = {0};
        length = 0;
        h = s + i;
        for(int j = i; j < len-1; j++){

            if (A[h[j]] == 1) {
                break;
            } else {
                A[h[j]] = 1;
                length +=1;
            }

            if (max < length) {
                max = length;
            }                
        }
    }

    return max;
}


int main() {        
    char *s = "amqpcsrumjjufpu";
    int ret = lengthOfLongestSubstring(s);
    printf("SAURABH: %d",ret);
}
```

Comment: Evidently you are trying to access index -3 of your array at some point.  You should do some debugging.

Comment: `char` is a signed type, so character 0xFC is being interpreted as -3. Try `uint8_t *h = (uint8_t *)s;`

Comment: @Saurabh dubey  The type char cab behave either as signed char or unsigned char. So you have explicitly to cast the expression h[j] to the type unsigned char. For example A[( unsigned char )h[j]] = 1;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Agreed, but to be precise, `char` may be either signed or unsigned, and has the same representation as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but it's always a distinct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to write a function that finds the length of the longest substring of unique characters.

For starters the function should be declared like

```
size_t lengthOfLongestSubstring( const char *s );
^^^^^^                           ^^^^^
```

These declarations in the outer scope of the function

```
int A[256] = {0};
//... 
int temp = 0;
```

are redundant. The variables are not used in the function.

The type `char` can behave either as the type `signed char` or the type `unsigned char`.  So in expressions like this `A[h[j]]` you have to cast explicitly the character used as index to the type `unsigned char` as for example

```
A[( unsigned char )h[j]]
```

The inner loop

```
for(int j=i;j<len-1;j++){
```

will not execute for strings that contain only one character. So it does not make sense as it is written.

This if statement

```
       if (max < length) {
                max = length ;
            }
```

needs to be placed outside the inner loop.

The algorithm used by you can be implemented the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

size_t lengthOfLongestSubstring(const char *s)
{
    size_t longest = 0;

    for (; *s; ++s )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        unsigned char letters[UCHAR_MAX] = { 0 };

        for ( const char *p = s; *p && !letters[(unsigned char)*p - 1]++; ++p) ++n;

        if (longest < n) longest = n;
    }

    return longest;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s = "123145";

    printf("The longest substring has %zu characters.\n",
        lengthOfLongestSubstring(s));

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The longest substring has 5 characters.
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for explaining it. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashed because you read data out of range, suppose your input string is *amqpcsrumjjufpu* its length is 15, in outer loop for `i = 13` you do assigment

```
h = s + i; // h was updated to indicate to 13th element of s
```

and in inner loop for first iteration, you read this element (j == i == 13)

```
A[h[j]]
```

so, you try to read this element `A[*(h+j)]`, but `h` indicates to 13th element of s, and now you try to add 13 to this value, you want to read 26th position of `s`, you are out of range of `s` string.

Comment: Got it.. it helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for responses. While Vlad's code worked for all the test cases, here is my code that also passed all the test cases after changes suggested by Vlad and rafix.

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char* s) {
    char *h = s;
    int max = 0;

    int len = strlen(s); 
    if (len == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < len;i ++){
        int A[256] = {0};
        int length = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < len; j++){

            if (A[(unsigned char)h[j]] == 1) {
                break;
            } else {
                A[(unsigned char) h[j]] = 1;
                length +=1;
            }

        }
        if (max < length) {
                max = length;
            }
    }

    return max;
}
```